# Use existing http server in spring boot as camel endpoint

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot, apache-camel, httpserver

I have a spring boot application that uses the spring boot starter web.  This creates a running Tomcat instance and sets up the http server running on a port.  Within my camel route, I want to use this http server as the component for http requests, but I can't figure out how to utilize it.  I see many many examples of configuring a jetty instance and consuming from it, but then wouldn't I in effect have two http servers running?  I only want to have one.  I assume the http server is already autowired up since I can consume from it with other spring code (such as a RestController) and I can see it started in my spring boot logs as well.

```
@Component
public class ExampleRoute extends RouteBuilder
{
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception
    {

        //@formatter:off

        from( <want to take in an http request here> )
            .log( LoggingLevel.INFO, log, "Hello World!" );

        //@formatter:on

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an example here: https://github.com/camelinaction/camelinaction2/tree/master/chapter7/springboot-camel

You can to register a `ServletRegistrationBean` that setup the Camel Servlet with Spring Boot.

```
@Bean
ServletRegistrationBean camelServlet() {
    // use a @Bean to register the Camel servlet which we need to do
    // because we want to use the camel-servlet component for the Camel REST service
    ServletRegistrationBean mapping = new ServletRegistrationBean();
    mapping.setName("CamelServlet");
    mapping.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    // CamelHttpTransportServlet is the name of the Camel servlet to use
    mapping.setServlet(new CamelHttpTransportServlet());
    mapping.addUrlMappings("/camel/*");
    return mapping;
}
```

However for Camel 2.19 we plan on make this simpler and OOTB: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-10416

And then you can do

```
from("servlet:foo")
  .to("bean:foo");
```

Where the HTTP url to call that Camel route will be `http:localhost:8080/camel/foo`

Comment: I had gone down the path of the servlet but wasn't able to get it to work.  However, using your @Bean above DID work.  As an aside: turns out you MUST give the ServletRegistrationBean a name and it MUST be "CamelServlet" or else it will not work (If I change it to say "MyCamelServlet" it does not initialize).  That was not clear from the examples and documentation.

Comment: That name has to match the name you find here in the table: http://camel.apache.org/servlet