# How to use Jetty from Spring Boot with Camel Jetty Component?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-camel, jetty

I have a Spring Boot application with Camel Endpoints routes using camel jetty component as a gateway.

```
@Component
public class StartEcommerce extends RouteBuilder {

  @Override
  public void configure() throws Exception {

    restConfiguration()
        .host("localhost")
        .port(8085);

    rest("/rest/v1")
        .post("/order")
            .to("direct:ecommerceRestRoute")
        .post("/cancelEnrollment")
            .to("direct:cancelEnrollmentRestRoute");

    // other routes ... 
  }
```

}

Everything works fine if I put the jetty component to execute in port 8085.

However, I would like to use Spring Boot's jetty that is already running in port 8081, because I want to have access to healthcheck endpoints from actuator and be able to call my rest endpoints like this:

```
localhost:8081/health
localhost:8081/rest/v1/order
localhost:8081/rest/v1/cancelEnrollment
```

Tried to follow this discussion

[Use existing http server in spring boot as camel endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40492458/use-existing-http-server-in-spring-boot-as-camel-endpoint)

but I got the error below, because I have two Jettys running on the same port

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Embedded servlet container failed to start. Port 8081 was already in use.

Action:

Identify and stop the process that's listening on port 8081 or configure this application to listen on another port.
```

I'm using camel-jetty 2.18.0 an Spring Boot 1.4.2.RELEASE.

Any suggestions how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, I have a incorrect dependency set in my build.gradle.

```
compile('org.apache.camel:camel-jetty:2.18.0')
```

Besides I remove the rest configuration from my route:

```
restConfiguration()
   .host("localhost")
   .port(8081);
```

And follow this example from Claus Ibsen

https://github.com/camelinaction/camelinaction2/blob/master/chapter7/springboot-camel/src/main/java/camelinaction/HelloRoute.java

Comment: Hi Higor Oliveira,

Did you end up using `servlet` component as explained in the github example link above? Can you please post your solution?

Cheers